# How to replace element with it's probability of belonging to class label if the label is in different Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame X_train containing a column 'state' having different(repeated) state names. In another Y_train DataFrame, I have class value 0-1.
In a dictionary variable Temp I have a probability of each state(unique) belonging to class 0 and 1.
**Now I want to replace all the state names in X_train with their probability score corresponds to class label in Y_train.**
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The data as you described:

```
import pandas as pd
X_train = pd.DataFrame([{'state': 'A'}, {'state': 'B'}, {'state': 'A'},{'state': 'A'}])
Y_train = pd.DataFrame([{'class': 1}, {'class': 0}, {'class': 1}, {'class': 1}])
Temp = {'A': {0: 0.75, 1: 0.25}, 'B': {0: 0.20, 1:0.8}}
```

Combined the two dataframes using a concat columnwise like so:

```
combined = pd.concat([X_train, Y_train], axis=1)
```

where axis=1 means you want to combine by column

Now run a double loop to assign the new values

```
for classname in combined['class'].unique():
     for state in combined['state'].unique():
          combined.loc[combined['class'] == classname, 'class'] = Temp[state][classname]
```

You'll end up with a combined looking like this:

```
  state  class
0     A   0.25
1     B   0.75
2     A   0.25
3     A   0.25
```

then just split up your data frames again

```
X_train = combined[['state']]
Y_train = combined[['class']]
```